# Removing last record terraform state in a terraform workspace

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am using terraform cloud workspaces.
By mistake, I upload the wrong terraform state to my workspace. Now my terraform plan is using it, but I don’t want to use it since that is not the state I wanted to get.

Let me explain with this image: I want to use the state from 10 months ago and not the New State I got recently:

[image]

I want to go back to my old state since in the new one there are no some resources and then they are being recreated in my terraform plan.
I am trying to import every separate resource, by executing `terraform import <RESOURCE-INSTANCE> <ID>` command in this way:

```
terraform import azurerm_app_service_plan.fem-plan /subscriptions/d37e88d5-e443-4285-98c9-91bf40d514f9/resourceGroups/rhd-spec-prod-rhdhv-1mo5mz5r2o4f6/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/fem-plan-afd1
Acquiring state lock. This may take a few moments...
azurerm_app_service_plan.fem-plan: Importing from ID "/subscriptions/d37e88d5-e443-4285-98c9-91bf40d514f9/resourceGroups/rhd-spec-prod-rhdhv-1mo5mz5r2o4f6/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/fem-plan-afd1"...
azurerm_app_service_plan.fem-plan: Import prepared!
  Prepared azurerm_app_service_plan for import
azurerm_app_service_plan.fem-plan: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/d37e88d5-e443-4285-98c9-91bf40d514f9/resourceGroups/rhd-spec-prod-rhdhv-1mo5mz5r2o4f6/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/fem-plan-afd1]


Error: Cannot import non-existent remote object

While attempting to import an existing object to
azurerm_app_service_plan.fem-plan, the provider detected that no object exists
with the given id. Only pre-existing objects can be imported; check that the
id is correct and that it is associated with the provider's configured region
or endpoint, or use "terraform apply" to create a new remote object for this
resource.

Releasing state lock. This may take a few moments...
```

But I got in the output, that resource does not exist, because terraform is using my latest **New state** where that resource is not included.

How can I use my old 10 months ago state?

If someone can point me out in the right path I will appreciate it.

Comment: Would these steps help? https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001151948-Modifying-Terraform-states-in-Terraform-Enterprise-or-Terraform-Cloud

Comment: Any updates on the question? Does it solve your problem?

Comment: @CharlesXu the support article provided by Adil-B above solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use the command `terraform refresh` to update the state file to match the current state of the resources. You can get the details of the command [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/refresh.html).